# stsadm -addsolution "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, web-parts

I am trying to deploy sharepoint webpart. Till executig in command prompt following command:

```
stsadm -o addsolution -filename {WSPFILENAME}
```

getting alway follow error: **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"**
no idea why. wspfilename is correct.
please help

Comment: you'll want to make sure you have proper permissions.  Try something like this:
stsadm -o enumsites -url http://localurlofyourfarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether you have enough permissions to the corresponding content database to which you are adding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, while deploying the solution from Visual Studio. I solved it by the Visual Studio and reopening it with **"Run as Administrator"**. This should give you the required permission.